# Group Policy directories remain as "opened" in Computer Management

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

On my domain controller (a Windows 2016 server), I have a number of opened directory as shown by Computer Management. For example, in the "Open Files" tab, I have quite a few entries as the following:

`C:\Windows\SYSVOL_DFSR\sysvol\example.com\Policies\{unique-policy-id}\Machine\Scripts\Startup`

It seems strange, as I have no startup/shutdown scripts. Moreover, I really expect the client to load the policy, execute it, and close the connection. Clients all are Windows 10 Pro.

Is this a sign of a problem, or it is expected behavior?